# Retrieve parts of text inside <li>

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have HTML like this

```
<li class="in-ttl-b">(a) kanji; a Chinese character [ideograph]
    <ul class="list-data-b-in"><li class="text-jejp text-c"><span class="ex">漢字で書く</span></li><li class="text-jeen text-c">write in <i>kanji</i> [<i>Chinese characters</i>]</li></ul>
    <ul class="list-data-b-in"><li class="text-jejp text-c"><span class="ex">常用漢字</span></li><li class="text-jeen text-c"><i>Chinese characters</i> for everyday use (in Japan)</li></ul>
</li>
```

How can I get only `kanji; a Chinese character [ideograph]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that by selecting the first *text node* that is child of the outer `li` element. For example, assuming there can be more than one instance of `li` with `class="in-ttl-b"` :

```
Dim lis = HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='in-ttl-b']")
For Each li As HtmlNode in lis 
    'select the first text node in <li> :
    Dim txt = li.SelectSingleNode("text()[1]")
    Console.WriteLine(li.InnerText)
Next
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/53KAt2)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
(a) kanji; a Chinese character [ideograph]
```