# Using HTMLAgilitypack to get data

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

```
<ol class="list-data-b">
<li class="in-ttl-b">(a) kanji; a Chinese character [ideograph]
    <ul class="list-data-b-in"><li class="text-jejp text-c"><span class="ex">漢字で書く</span></li><li class="text-jeen text-c">write in <i>kanji</i> [<i>Chinese characters</i>]</li></ul>
    <ul class="list-data-b-in"><li class="text-jejp text-c"><span class="ex">常用漢字</span></li><li class="text-jeen text-c"><i>Chinese characters</i> for everyday use (in Japan)</li></ul>
</li>
</ol>
```

I have HTML like that, how can i get a part of data:

- (a) kanji; a Chinese character [ideograph]
- 漢字で書く
- write in kanji [Chinese characters]
- 常用漢字
- Chinese characters for everyday use (in Japan)

This is my code.

```
Dim node2 = HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='list-data-b-in']")
        If node2 IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each node In node2
                Dim Japnodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//li[@class='text-jejp text-c']")
                txtMean.AppendText(Japnodes.InnerText)
                txtMean.AppendText(vbNewLine)
                Dim Engnodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = node.SelectSingleNode("//li[@class='text-jeen text-c']")
                txtMean.AppendText(Engnodes.InnerText)
                txtMean.AppendText(vbNewLine)
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the first text can be done as explained in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569210/retrieve-parts-of-text-inside-li). Now to get each pair of Chinese/Japanese-English texts, you can iterate through the `ul` elements, and then, from each `ul`, get the two elements that contain the target text.

Here is a console application demo :

```
Dim lis = HTMLDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='in-ttl-b']")
For Each li As HtmlNode in lis 
    Dim txt = li.SelectSingleNode("text()[1]")
    Console.WriteLine(txt.InnerText)
    For Each ul As HtmlNode in li.SelectNodes("ul")
        Dim japNode = ul.SelectSingleNode("li/span")
        Dim engNode = ul.SelectSingleNode("li[@class='text-jeen text-c']")

        Console.WriteLine(japNode.InnerText)
        Console.WriteLine(engNode.InnerText)
    Next
Next
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zmdbBd)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
(a) kanji; a Chinese character [ideograph]

漢字で書く
write in kanji [Chinese characters]
常用漢字
Chinese characters for everyday use (in Japan)
```